# Block duplicates when adding to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in JavaScript. I have this code:

```
var imageArray = [];

$(document).on("click", ".showPrv", function () {
    $("#dropzone").each(function () {
        $(".dz-image-preview").each(function () {
            $(".dz-image").each(function () {
                imageArray.push($(this).find("img").attr("src"))
            });
        });
    });
    console.log(imageArray);
})
```

This code works fine, but I have a problem with duplicates in my array imageArray. How can you block duplicates from being added to this table?

Comment: use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `includes()` function.

Using it will be:

```
...
$(".dz-image").each(function () {
    if(!imageArray.includes($(this).find("img").attr("src")))
        imageArray.push($(this).find("img").attr("src"))
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value exists in the imageArray before pushing a new one, somewhat like this:

```
   const imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
   if(!imageArray.includes(imgSrc)) {
       imageArray.push(imgSrc);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for this, as it allows for a quick lookups (*O(1)*) in order to check if the value already exists. Using an array forces you to do `.includes()` which takes *O(n)* time.

```
const imageSet = new Set();
...
const imgSrcAttr = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
if(!imageSet.has(imgSrcAttr)) {
   imageSet.add(imgSrcAttr);
}
...
```

If at some point you need to convert the set to an array, you can simply use the *spread*-operator:

```
const imageArr = [...imageSet];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element was not found, `-1` will be returned. Refer to [$.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
// If not in your array then
if($.inArray($(this).find("img").attr("src"), imageArray) === -1){

     // Add value to imageArray
     imageArray.push($(this).find("img").attr("src"));
}
```

Example of `$.inArray()` on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4r2r/14/) for better understanding.